# Module not found: Can't resolve 'ipfs-http-client' in '/home/ubuntu/chatapp/src/components'

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-20.04, ipfs-http-client

I am trying to send files to ipfs. I am using the ipfs-http-client module. when I am trying to compile with this I keep getting this error :

Module not found: Can't resolve 'ipfs-http-client' in '/home/ubuntu/chatapp/src/components'

I installed the module using the command specified in the official docs - "npm install --save ipfs-http-client" . I can see the module in my dependencies but still getting this error.
version shows in the dependency is 60.0.0
I am a completely new to this and doing this according to a youtube video. A little help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

this is the code I am using

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.png';
import './App.css';


const ipfsClient = require('ipfs-http-client')
const ipfs = ipfsClient({host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port:'5001', protocol: 'https'})

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buffer: null
    };
  }



  captureFile = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    //processs file for IPFS
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const reader = new window.FileReader()
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({buffer: Buffer(reader.result)})
      }
  }

  onSubmit = async(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("submitting the form...")
    await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer,(error,result) => {
      console.log('ipfs result', result)
      if(error) {
        console.error(error)
        return
      }
      //do stuff here
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
          <a
            className="navbar-brand col-sm-3 col-md-2 mr-0"
            href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            File Sharing Application
          </a>
        </nav>
        <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
          <div className="row">
            <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 d-flex text-center">
              <div className="content mr-auto ml-auto">
                <a
                  href="http://www.dappuniversity.com/bootcamp"
                  target="_blank"
                  rel="noopener noreferrer"
                >
                  <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                </a>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <h2>Change</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} >
                  <input type='file' onChange={this.captureFile} />
                  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
                </form>

                
              </div>
            </main>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix CJS and ESM, and make sure you check [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client?activeTab=readme#getting-started) to see how to use the module. `import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'` — but you also can't use the module directly in React without some extra config ([see the docs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/packages/ipfs-http-client#in-a-web-browser)).